# How to implement the DecomposeMe architecture in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

There is a type of architecture that I would like to experiment with in TensorFlow.

The idea is to compose 2-D filter kernels by a combination of 1-D filters.

From the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05426):

> **Simplifying ConvNets through Filter Compositions**
>
> The essence of our proposal consists of decomposing the ND kernels of a traditional network into N consecutive layers of 1D kernels.
>   ...
>   We propose DecomposeMe which is an architecture consisting of decomposed layers. Each decomposed layer represents a N-D convolutional layer as a composition of 1D filters and, in addition, by including a non-linearity
>   φ(·) in-between.
>   ...
>   Converting existing structures to decomposed ones is a straight forward process as
>   **each existing ND convolutional layer can systematically be decomposed into sets of
>   consecutive layers consisting of 1D linearly rectified kernels and 1D transposed kernels**
>   as shown in Figure 1.

If I understand correctly, a single 2-D convolutional layer is replaced with two consecutive 1-D convolutions?

Considering that the weights are shared and transposed, it is not clear to me how exactly to implement this in TensorFlow.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old and you probably already figured it out, but it might help someone else with the same problem.

Separable convolution can be implemented in tensorflow as follows (details omitted):

```
X= placeholder(float32, shape=[None,100,100,3]);
v1=Variable(truncated_normal([d,1,3,K],stddev=0.001));
h1=Variable(truncated_normal([1,d,K,N],stddev=0.001));
M1=relu(conv2(conv2(X,v1),h1));
```

Standard 2d convolution with a column vector is the same as convolving each column of the input with that vector. Convolution with v1 produces K feature maps (or an output image with K channels), which is then passed on to be convolved by h1 producing the final desired number of featuremaps N.

**Weight sharing**, according to my knowledge, is simply a a misleading term, which is meant to emphasize the fact that you use one filter that is convolved with each patch in the image. Obviously you're going to use the same filter to obtain the results for each output pixel, which is how everyone does it in image/signal processing.

Then in order to "decompose" a convolution layer as shown on page 5, it can be done by simply adding activation units in between the convolutions (ignoring biases):

```
M1=relu(conv2(relu(conv2(X,v1)),h1));
```

Not that each filter in v1 is a column vector [d,1], and each h1 is a row vector [1,d]. The paper is a little vague, but when performing separable convolution, this is how it's done. That is, you convolve the image with the column vectors, then you convolve the result with the horizontal vectors, obtaining the final result.